# Can an individual apple developer account have your own name/studio's name?

Tags: appstore

I just purchased the iOS developer program for $99. It said on the website that the sellers name would be your name. I think Ketchapp (the creator of 2048) also uses individual. So are you allowed to use a name you created yourself to be your individual account's name? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iOS developer program policy, not game development.

Answer (score 1):

This is my *personal experience* from having set up and used two different developer programs over the last few years. As such, there may be a way to work around the things I state below, but I have not found them.

**Look at the bottom for a tl;dr.**

When I enrolled in a Personal Developer Program in  June 2011, for my personal App Business Street Samurai Studios, I was allowed to set a Developer Name that would appear in the App store and I put in "Street Samurai Studios". I was also given notice that I would not be able to (ever) change the name once I had put it in.

Now, when it was time to start up my second business venture, in August 2013, me and my Co-Founders decided to start out with a personal developer account until we had registered our business properly. Once enrolled I assumed I would be given the same option to put in a Developer Name, but I was not. As such, we had to go with the First and Last name of the person who registered the account (me), until we migrated it into a Business Developer Account.

I was in contact with Apple via phone to ask them for assistance and was told that the aforementioned option HAD been available before, but was withdrawn some time ago. However, account that had already been set up with this option (e.g. my first one and, we assume, KetchApps) were allowed to keep the Developer Names.

One thing that might work, though I'm not sure it's possible, or allowed, is to set up a new Apple Account with your studio name as the First and Last name of the Account. Like I said, I'm not sure this is possible or allowed, but it might be worth a shot.

**TL;DR;**
1. No, you cannot provide a developer name other than the First and Last name registered with the Apple Account. 
2. You could before, hence KetchApps name, but not anymore.
3. You could try registering a new Apple Account with your developer name as First and Last name, but I do not know if this works, or if it's allowed by Apple.

Comment: So you can't have your own name without a bussiness? Thats sad :( How come alot of people use names like eg: LOTUM Apps, BitMango, Dreamics? How did they do that? Do you need to contact apple for that or something?

Comment: If you enroll in the Developer program prior to a certain date (I'm not sure which, but somewhere between June 2011 and August 2013), you could put in a developer name (that's what I did with Street Samurai Studios), but nowadays you can't. 

Either the ones you mention enrolled in the developer program before this date or they have a company account, which you are viable for as soon as you have a registered business and receive a DUNS number.